# Parse the xml and replace a string value in xml tag using ansible

Tags: xpath, ansible

I am using Ansible playbook to extract a specific attribute value from an XML file to replace, as prescribed in the Ansible XML module page. But not sure about this scenario where XML tags are deep-rooted. I would like to know how to replace this tag value using the XML XPath module in ansible.

Sample XML file for easy understanding:

```
# <business type="bar">
#   <name>Tasty Beverage Co.</name>
#     <beers type="A">
#       <beerPrice>100</beer>
#       <beerName>Schlitz</beer>
#    </beers>
#    <beers type="B">
#       <beerPrice>200</beer>
#       <beerName>Old Curmudgeon</beer>
#    </beers>
#    <beers type="C">
#       <beerPrice>200</beer>
#       <beerName>Old Granny</beer>
#    </beers>
#   <rating subjective="true">10</rating>
#   <website>
#     <mobilefriendly/>
#     <address>http://tastybeverageco.com</address>
#   </website>
# </business>
```

Above, I would like to change the beerPrice to 300 from 200 for beers type "B".
Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below sample task will replace `beerPrice` of `<beers type="B">` to `300`.
You can extend this sample by using loops, variables etc. and other specific xpath expressions.

```yaml
- xml:
    path: file1.xml
    xpath: /business/beers[@type='B']/beerPrice
    value: '300'
    state: present
```

**UPDATE**

---

Below example modifies `type` attribute of `<beers type="B">` to `<beers type="XL">`.

```yaml
- xml:
    path: file1.xml
    xpath: /business/beers[@type='B']
    value: XL
    attribute: type
    state: present
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try this out.

Comment: @Moon what will be the playbook if i want to change type= "B" beer to "XL" beer for example

Comment: @TAMIMHAIDER Added a sample in the update section.

Comment: ERROR! 'xml' is not a valid attribute for a Play